# Disable double click in Android PhoneGap App

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm using `PhoneGap` for building an Android App.
The PhoneGap app loads an `WebViwe` with my site. I have problems when user double click on items and makes me some problems...

How can I cancel the option of double clicking? I mean each double tap would result one tap.

Answer (score 0):

This could be two different issues. In Android the webview has a click delay that waits for double click actions and adds 300ms before completing click actions. For that you can use the JS library `fastclick.js` [get it here](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

To use it add this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false);
```

You could also add an event handler for `dblclick` with this:

```
window.addEventLister('dblclick', someFunctionOnDblClick, false);
```

Comment: `window.addEventLister('dblclick'` don't work for mobile clicks...not for Android as I tested